# Problem with NSToolbar when window open programmatically

Tags: macos, swift4, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nstoolbar

I am making an app where at the begging it check if a value exist in UserDefaults. If not, it opens a window asking the user to choose where to put a Database and save the path in UserDefaults. If the Path is already hear, then the main window opens.

To do this I have two storyboard, the Main containing all the controllers for the main window and the Welcome storyboard containing the welcome screen.

My main window contains a NSToolbar with items. the problem is that if I put my main window controller as initial controller, the toolbar just work fine, but the Welcome screen is never called. So I've remove the "is initial controller" options, but if check the conditions in applicationDidFinishLaunching in appDelegate, when I instantiate the window from here (and everything works, the right window is open for the right condition), the Toolbar never works (the actions for the buttons are never called, I checked with prints).

Here's my code in appDelegate :

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if userDefaults.string(forKey: "Database Path") == nil {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)
        let initiate = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as! WelcomeWindowController
        initiate.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    } else {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initiate = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! MainWindowController
        initiate.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

    }

}
```

Is there something I'm missing when I instantiate the main window controller?

Comment: `initiate` is released when it goes out of scope. Store the window controller in a property.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I tried previously to store the window, but I didn't think to try to store the window controller.